# Joomla 2.5 installer: cUrl cannot find domain.tld/extension.xml with HTTP 302 Found instead of HTTP 200

Tags: joomla-2.5, curl

I've been trying the "find updates" in Joomla for a few extensions, where I only get error messages such as
Unable to open http://www.keashly.net/updates/kc_cufon.xml

You can perfectly open and retrieve the xml directly from a webbrowser, but in cUrl this results in

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 21 Feb 2015 17:11:35 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.keashly.net/
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Sat, 21 Feb 2015 18:11:35 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 207
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href=\"http://www.keashly.net/\">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

I've tried explicitly setting the Host header and HTTP Version to 1.1, but nothing helps so far. Looking into a Net Panel in the browser there doesn't appear to be any redirect at all.
Would you have any idea of what I'd need to do to get the file?
Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Have you considered reaching out to the extension developer? While there may be someone in this community with experience in this extension, your best bet is to follow up with the developer directly.

Comment: If you downvote a question, it would be most appreciated if you could comment with your reasoning, so that I might be able to avoid annoying you again in the future.

Comment: @johanpw This wasn't extension specific but apparently a request issue. It appears that some webserver block requests without a (valid?) User-Agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah sorry, I just found an answer. Apparently many servers reject requests without a proper user agent given. 
Adding USERAGENT to my options sorted the issue

```
$options[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] = isset($userAgent) ? $userAgent : "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
```